# Text reaching over the specified width of its DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, width

EDIT: Another image to further showcase my issue:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/cvtc.png/

I know this question has been asked but every solution I have tried has not worked, i.e.: word-wrap, text-wrap, overflow-wrap.

I have text that I have measure to be 344px in width, and would like the rest of my texts to meet that boundary and/or not flow over it. I keep setting this specified width of 344 or even less and this last set of text especially is just causing issues. Here is a screen shot of the issue as well as my HTML and CSS. Any help is appreciated!

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/1fj8.png/]

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jessica ___: PORTFOLIO</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
    <body>

<div id="letter-container" class="letter-container">
                <div id="heading">HELLO</div>
                <div id="aboutintro">My name is</div>
                <div id="name">jessica ___</div>
                <div id="aboutbody">and I'm a student at the College of Design, Architecture, Art, and Planning of the University of Cincinnati and I like to design websites and take pictures.</div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#heading").lettering();
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
      $("#aboutintro").delay(4000).fadeIn(500);
      });
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#name").lettering();
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
       $("#aboutbody").delay(6000).fadeIn(500);
       });
       </script>

    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */


     html { 
     background: url(grungebg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     }


     @font-face {
     font-family: 'league_gothicregular';
     src: url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot');
     src: url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.svg#league_gothicregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    }

    .letter-container
    {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:344px;
text-align:center;
    }

    #heading {
font-family: league_gothicregular, sans-serif;
    }

    #heading span {
font-size: 200px;
background-image: url(mask.png);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
-webkit-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
-moz-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
-ms-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(1) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.2s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2.2s;
animation-delay: 2.2s;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.6s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2.6s;
animation-delay: 2.6s;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.9s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.9s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2.9s;
animation-delay: 2.9s;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2.4s;
animation-delay: 2.4s;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
-moz-animation-delay: 3s;
-ms-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    #heading span:nth-child(6) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
-ms-animation-delay: 2.7s;
animation-delay: 2.7s;
    }
    }
    @keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
     }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    #aboutintro
    {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size:65px;
font-weight:300;
color:white;
display:none;
    }
    #name{
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
font-size:65px;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
background-image: url(mask.png);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
-webkit-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
-moz-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
-ms-animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
animation: sharpen 0.6s linear backwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 5s;
-ms-animation-delay: 5s;
animation-delay: 5s;
text-align:center;
    }
    }
    @keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes sharpen {
    0% {
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    90% {
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
    color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    }




    #aboutbody
    {
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:400px;
color:#e5e5e5;
display:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0;
margin:0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the text is 344px? with your CSS the small text couldn't take any more space than that specified in `.letter-container`. I suggest you use your browser's inspection tools to analyze the size of the elements in your page

Comment: How do I get to browser inspection tools? I am using Chrome, by the way. The only way I've been able to see the width of text is through screen shots and Photoshop. I felt it was accurate since nothing I have right now is responsive or fluid.

Comment: F12 should bring up the Developer Tools window, the first tab shows your DOM structure, highlighting over an element shows a small tooltip with its size

Comment: Yeah, the tools are showing me that the text that says "HELLO" is smaller than 344px, but I'm not sure why when I take a screen shot it isn't accurate. I'm not sure how else to measure it, I guess I will just have to go down pixels until I reach it and see how that goes. Thanks for telling me about the tools, I never knew it existed

Comment: I went ahead and took a screen shot as I used the tools. The heading text is indeed the width of 344 px, but the rest is conforming to the width of 379 px even when I set each individual DIV or element to a width of 344 px. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/cvtc.png/

Comment: The image shows the `#heading` container being 344px, the "HELLO" text is actually smaller than that, I don't know why you're getting that discrepancy between Chrome and Photoshop, maybe you have zoomed in in Chrome?

Comment: I'm not zoomed in Chrome at all. I have my browser window full screen as well. It says 344px when you hover over the elements but if you measure that blue highlight it uses, the highlight is not 344px. I think the highlight is misleading and doesn't show the true size, because even though it says 344px, it measures to 379px.

Comment: That's weird, I've never had a problem with Chrome Tools not giving the right dimensions, in fact I just tested with a screenshot from an element and when measured in both Photoshop and Fireworks I get the right value. Maybe it's a Mac issue? Try with another browser and see what value you get

Comment: I'm getting the right value in Firefox (though my site is not actually working because the background-clip property is not supported :() and it shows that the text is smaller than 344. I'm not sure why it is an issue in Chrome. I really did not want a Mac. It was a requirement of my university. I took my screen shots, one from Firefox and one from Chrome, and put them both under the same guides and I'm getting that difference still. I'm thinking maybe even though my zoom is on 100% in both, maybe they are still different values next to each other? It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: miro asked for a .zip of my web page, maybe it will help haha https://www.dropbox.com/s/bghp5652oupqpzm/Current%20Web%20Work%202.zip

Comment: Well testing in my machine Chrome reports the same thing, "HELLO" is smaller than 344px, I get the same result when measuring in Photoshop, now I'm starting to think the issue lies in your screenshots because those are certainly reporting other sizes. Anyway you may just want to set the width of your container to 326px, that's the actual size of the text, you can test it yourself by setting `position:absolute` on `#heading` and measuring using the inspection tools

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, koala_dev. I'm sure it was frustrating just thinking it through. I ended up just choosing a width and sizing my text as close as I could to match, and did everything else that way too and it looks pretty good now. Took longer than I wanted but it was worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this? If your text takes up more than 344px, then it will be cut off rendering some of it unreadable.

```
.letter-container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-width:344px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's the issue: I want to be able to read all my text. I don't want it to be weirdly sliced into. :/

Comment: Well, if the text inside of the div is long enough, then there's no way to get around it. check my updated answer to see if that helps

Comment: That is minimum width, isn't that the smallest it can be but it can still be larger is the browser allows it? I want it to be exactly or under 344 px.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to change the font size if the string length exceeds a certain amount. You'll need JS for that. Nothing that CSS can do for you here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is [the FitText plugin](http://fittextjs.com/)

It will scale your text to a width relative to the the with of the screen.

Althoug in your case you might want to scale the text to the width of the parent element in which case you can try using my script (not yet plugin): http://mirohristov.com/mirofittext/

P.S. You forgot to remove your full name from the address bar in chrome and the upper right corner of your mac.

Comment: Yes, I would like the text to scale to the width of the DIV it is inside of. How do I use your script, since it is not a plugin and I do not see any place to download it?

Comment: Actually, I thought about it further. I'm not sure that this would work because I don't want the height of my text to change, I want the font sizes I have. I just don't want the lines of text to reach over the width of 344 px. If one line gets to it or is about to, I want it to go to the next line automatically without using a break.

Comment: Can you provide link to the webiste or zip file? It's hard to work with screenshots and just code.

Comment: Let me know if this works https://www.dropbox.com/s/bghp5652oupqpzm/Current%20Web%20Work%202.zip

Comment: Got it. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3770842/jessica/enter2.zip
Let me know if this works for you. I added an empty character at the end '|' and then set it opacity 0. The reason you have problems with that text because of the text-clipping in combination with italic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do this without using a fixed size, the trick is to make the container fit to the size of its content using `display:inline-block` and removing everything but the `#heading` ("HELLO" text) from the document flow using a wrapper container:

**HTML**

```
<div id="letter-container" class="letter-container">
    <div id="heading">HELLO!</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="aboutintro">My name is</div>
        <div id="name">jessica ___</div>
        <div id="aboutbody">and I'm a student at the College of Design, Architecture, Art, and Planning of the University of Cincinnati and I like to design websites and take pictures.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    text-align: center; /*We need this since we are moving from block elements to inline-blocks*/
}

#letter-container
{
    display: inline-block; /*Fit to content*/
    position: relative; /*Base for #content positioning/dimension */
}

#heading {
    font-family: league_gothicregular, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block; /* Fit to content */
}

#content{
    position: absolute; /*Remove from document flow*/
    width: 100%; /*Set the width to that of the container*/
    box-sizing:border-box; /*This is just here to align the borders below*/
}

/*Some test borders to illustrate alignment*/
#heading, #content{
    border-right: solid 1px red;
    border-left: solid 1px red;
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about measuring the actual size of the text and no change is needed if you ever decide to change the text of the heading.

Now I also I want to give you a couple of notes on your code:

1. You're loading both jquery and the lettering plugin twice in your page, those references should only be made once.
2. You don't need a separate `<script>` tag or `$(function(){})` for every piece of jquery code, in fact it's better if you only have a single document ready handler in your page, ex:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $("#heading,#name").lettering();
       $("#aboutintro").delay(4000).fadeIn(500);
       $("#aboutbody").delay(6000).fadeIn(500);
   });
   </script>
   ```